# LARAVEL 5.6 - What's wrong with my Login form ? Can not login the existing user

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller, authentication

As in subject, today i'm creating a Login panel with new Laravel 5.6. Simply i used an included Laravel's Panel with User Model and i created UserController :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UserController extends Controller
{


//  Auto loading middleware
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function add()
    {
        return view('User.add');
    }



    public function save(Request $request)
    {

        // Metoda 1
        User::create($request->all());

    }

    public function login()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }


    public function register()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

}
```

That's Laravel view "login" refactored by me :

```
<main>
    <section class="well-md well-md--inset-3 marker relative">
        <div class="container-fluid container-inset">
            @if(!empty($msg))
                    {{ $msg }}
            @endif
            <h2 class="text-center text-md-left">Logowanie</h2>
            <form class='rd-mailform' method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                @csrf

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="row flow-offset">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                            <label data-add-placeholder="">
                                <input type="text"
                                       name="email"
                                       class="{{$errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : ''}}" value="{{ old('email')}}"
                                       required autofocus
                                       placeholder="Twój email"
                                       data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Email"/>
                            </label>


                            <label data-add-placeholder="">
                                <input type="password"
                                       name="haslo"
                                       class="{{$errors->has('haslo') ? ' is-invalid' : ''}}" value="{{ old('haslo')}}"
                                       required autofocus
                                       placeholder="Hasło"
                                       data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Password"/>
                            </label>




                            <label>

                                <div class="remember">Zapamiętaj</div>
                                <div class="justify-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
                                </div>



                            </label>


                        </div>
                        <div class="mfControls text-center text-lg-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-md uppercase " type="submit">Wyślij</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mfInfo"></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

And here are my routes :

```
// Not protected sites
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@welcome');

Route::get('/onas' , [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@onas',
    'as' => 'Home@onas'
]);

Route::get('/cennik' , [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@cennik',
    'as' => 'Home@cennik'
]);

Route::get('/samochody' , [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@samochody',
    'as' => 'Home@samochody'
]);

Route::get('/uslugi' , [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@uslugi',
    'as' => 'Home@uslugi'
]);

Route::get('/konto' , [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@konto',
    'as' => 'Home@konto'
]);



Route::get('/kontakt' , [
    'uses' => 'MailController@kontakt',
    'as' => 'Mail@kontakt'
]);

Route::post('/kontakt' , 'MailController@wyslij');


// Protected routes
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{

    Route::get('/add' , 'UserController@add');


    Route::post('/save' , [                 // Tablica taka posiada wiele różnych kluczy
        'uses' => 'UserController@save' ,
        'as' => 'User.Save'
    ]);

    Route::get('/show/{user}' , [
        'uses' => 'UserController@show' ,
        'as' => 'User.Show'
    ]);

    Route::get('/login' , 'UserController@login');

    Route::get('/register' , 'UserController@register');
```

Database migration :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('imie');
            $table->string('nazwisko');
            $table->string('ulica');
            $table->string('numer');
            $table->string('kod-pocztowy');
            $table->string('miasto');
            $table->string('telefon');
            $table->string('nip');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('haslo');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

My question is, why i can not login the user ? Database columns are matched. Please help me guys !

Comment: Your login function is doing nothing but loading a view, where did you write logic for user authentication?

Comment: ahhh, i thought it works "automatically" as built-in. So the all i need is to write a logic for Users authentication, right ?

Comment: Yup... correct. You can create another route e.g. checkLogin , update form action route to checkLogin and write authentication codes in new routes. Let me know if have any difficulty. Thank you.

Comment: To check an example, you can follow - https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-login-authentication/

Comment: Ok, going to try by myself if it will be too difficult for me i will contact you, thank you very much !